# How to accumulate several API call responses in Apache Nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I should run an remote API in Nifi and response is a Json like this:

```
{"data":[{...}, {...}, ...],"nextPage":"http://example.com/nextCall"}
```

I must continue to call the API and accumulate "data" until nextPage becomes null.
I have implemented it by using attributes and DistributedCacheServer, but it is not optimum, because data has about 1000 element and every element is a Json with several keys and values.
**Updated Feb 16 2019:**
This is my work flow:
[image]

This is my Multipage Handler:
https://gist.github.com/behrouz-s/01f9fe1c09ac9d54d0adf3cdd011ea1d

Comment: what you are going to do with accumulated data?

Comment: This is a serrvice that make several calls unnecessitate for users. I want to sent them back as a response to API caller. @daggett

Comment: could you share your flow and the logic, because i can't understand what distributed cache map doing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the idea:

1. at input you have a valid json as content (for example null), target url in some attribute,
2. cycle point: set request `fragment.identifier=${UUID()}` , and `fragment.count=2`
3. you transfer this file in two directions:

   - fragment=0 goes to merge and waits there the second file that will contain http response
   - fragment=1 goes through invokehttp
4. merge uses binary concat and always waits for 2 files
5. if next url is valid goto 2

[image]